# Kafka Go Confluent package - Producer and Consumer fail logs

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

**SCENARIO**

We have a use case where we consume events from a topic in our microservice and eventually after certain business flows we produce multiple events to different topic(s).

*Service -> Consume and then multiple Produce*

We see below logs after a few hours when the service is actively running

```
|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-2| [thrd:sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2]: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2: Timed out ProduceRequest in flight (after 60728ms, timeout #0)
|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-2| [thrd:sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2]: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2: Timed out 1 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-2| [thrd:sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2]: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/2: 1 request(s) timed out: disconnect (after 706381222ms in state UP)

|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: {{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092: Disconnected (after 345599852ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
error: Local: Broker transport failure: GroupCoordinator: {{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092: Disconnected (after 345599852ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)

|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/0]: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/0: Disconnected (after 345600240ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
error: Local: Broker transport failure: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/0: Disconnected (after 345600240ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/8]: sasl_ssl://{{placeholder}}.aws.confluent.cloud:9092/8: Disconnected (after 345600352ms in state UP, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

**OTHER DETAILS**

confluent-kafka-go version - v1.7.0 (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/)

Kafka Cluster : Confluent Platform Basic plan (since we are in development phase now)

**Consumer config** -

```
{
UserName: username,
Password: password,
Brokers: broker,
Topics: []string{kafkaConfig.CONSUMER_TOPIC},
ConsumerGroup: kafkaConfig.CONSUMER_GROUP,
FetchMinBytes: 1000,
PollTimeout: 100,
}
```

**Producer config** -

```
{
UserName: username,
Password: password,
Brokers: broker,
Topic: kafkaConfig.PRODUCER_TOPIC,
BatchSize: 100000,
LingerMs: 10,
}
```

*The service runs on kubernetes pods deployed on EKS (AWS)*

**QUESTIONS/QUERIES** : We as a team are new to Kafka and golang. So would appreciate below queries to be answered.

- Any specific reason we see these logs?
- We create producer during the start of the application and that remains a single producer throughout the application lifecycle. Do producers have a timeout/expiry ? Other option for us is to create producers at the time of producing messages but in that case we will end up creating many(in order of thousands) producers. What should be the best way to handle this scenario ?
- Are there any other configurations or better practices you may want to recommend ?

Comment: Seems the `{{placeholder}}` was not replaced before used in the connection string...

Answer (score 0):

What I can say is DO NOT EVER create many Kafka producers on runtime and remain with the one you create at the start of application's life cycle (Otherwise you're likely to experience notable performance issues and probably high memory consumption).

The reason you see these logs is probably just to note that Broker or Kafka client is idle for some time. I am not experienced with Confluent Cloud but I'm also using the Confluent Kafka packages with Kafka Brokers On-Prem and I've seen these logs when my consumer or producer were idle for some hours and it wasn't an error really - the application kept running normally as soon as new messages were consumed. Please check out [this discussion](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/559) for more info.